# How to set non-model field property to all the objects in ManyToMany Relation?

Tags: python, django

I have a django model, with ManyToMany relation, and through a recursive function I am trying to set a custom property on the main model and all the models in the ManyToMany fields, but ManyToMany related model property is not getting reflected into the templates.

Here is my code snippet:

```
def update_product_price_details(product):
        product.sale_price = product.original_price

        if product.product_type == "PACKAGED_PRODUCT":
            product_discount = ProductServices.get_product_discount(product) # TODO : handle multiple items
            # calculate product sale price base on subproducts and its disocunt
            product.original_price  = 0
            for sub_product  in product.packagedproduct.sub_products.all():
                sub_product = ProductServices.update_product_price_details(sub_product)
                product.original_price = product.original_price + sub_product.sale_price

            if product_discount and product_discount.is_valid():
                product.sale_price = product.original_price - (product.original_price*product_discount.discount_percentage/100)

        else:
            product_discount = ProductServices.get_product_discount(product) # TODO : handle multiple items
            # if valid discount set new price as sale_price
            if product_discount and product_discount.is_valid():
                product.sale_price = product.original_price - (product.original_price*product_discount.discount_percentage/100)

        return product
```

#### CODE EXPLANATION

I will pass a Product Model to `update_product_price_details(product)` and for each sub product I am calculating the `sale_price`, then finally I will calculate the `PACAKGED_PRODUCT` `sale_price`.

```
sub_product = ProductServices.update_product_price_details(sub_product)
```

The value setting to sub_product via above line of code is not reflected to actual product model.

Is there a way to update the ManyToMany field model with a custom property? Totally stuck here, please help.

Many Many Thanks.

Comment: One way I would have done it is when I am looping through M2M field in template I could make use of model functions, reason being you are calculating it on Product instance. So you can have a model function called get_updated_price_details on Product model, easy to access in template.

Comment: Let me know if I was unclear on something, explaining things is not something I am good at :P On the second thoughts can you share your ProductServices ?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar Thanks, Got it what you said, that will work out.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar is there a way we can access the m2m items by index?

Comment: Yes you can, but I am wondering why would you do it.

Comment: Yea, Thanks. This is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of model functions is a simple solution to it, nice and clean.